# Why `(9999).toLocaleString('es')` doesn't print the thousand separator?

Tags: javascript, locale, number-formatting

This problem seems to happen for every number between `1000` to `9999.99999...` when using any spanish locale

```js
(9999.99).toLocaleString('es')
"9999,99"   // should be "9.999,99"

(10000.01).toLocaleString('es')
"10.000,01"
```

Is this a bug or part of the locale standard?.

*Tested in the console on Chrome and Firefox*

Comment: Why do you think it should print the separator?

Comment: @Nit Windows-Excel does, and I find it suspicious that most(probably all) spanish locales works this way

Comment: looks like it's how `es` locale is specified - so the code works as expected

Comment: Nobody in the spanish-speaker world would think this is correct behavior, it's clearly a bug. Someone with enough authority "designed" it to be that way and now buggy implementations roam the world. This is what happens when commitees don't align with the real-world.

Comment: @Alejandro I believe so too, but I don't like to generalize, so my experiences are in the financial sector of Venezuela, Perú and with less confidence Colombia, and I'm pretty sure it's written 1.000